# Extracting unique keyword and count from dataframe column

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I need to display distinct keyword and its frequency (count) from queires searched on Google.
then I need to select top 10 words by their frequency.

Input example:

| site | query |
| --- | --- |
| google.com | https://www.google.com/search?q=shoe+store+in+new+york |
| google.com | https://www.google.com/search?q=new+york+attractions |

Output example if df is chosen for displaying results:

| keyword | count |
| --- | --- |
| shoe | 1 |
| store | 1 |
| in | 1 |
| new | 2 |
| york | 2 |
| attractions | 1 |

So I extracted the keywords from queries but I don't really know what to do next.
I'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use to count keywords from a url containing a query:

```
from collections import Counter
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

def get_keywords_count(url):
    return Counter(parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q'][0].split())
```

Example of usage:

```
>>> get_keywords_count('https://www.google.com/search?q=shoe+store+in+new+york')
Counter({'shoe': 1, 'store': 1, 'in': 1, 'new': 1, 'york': 1})
```

You can now use it with your dataframe to get the total count:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    df['query'].apply(get_keywords_count).sum().items(),
    columns=['keyword', 'count'],
)
```

```
>>> result
       keyword  count
0         shoe      1
1        store      1
2           in      1
3          new      2
4         york      2
5  attractions      1
```

Comment: Thank you! what does the ['q'][0] stand for? I assume its porpuse is to extract query after 'q', so it actually doesnt work on the extracted list of keywords I already have

Comment: @Vic Exactly, it extracts the query from the url. Didn't you need it?

Comment: Yes, just trying to get the general idea. I tried for example to use this on a url of a different form - 'airbnb.com/s/New-York--NY--United-States/' so I replaced the 'q' with 's/' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Vic You should check what a query string is within a url ;) Your example does not contain a query string

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `sort_values` pandas method.

For your example:

```
import pandas as pd

keyword_count_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'keyword':['shoe', 'store', 'in', 'new', 'york', 'attractions'],
    'count':[1,1,1,2,2,1]
})

keyword_count_df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better ways to do this, but here's mine;

```
results = ['the','the','plane','bus','plane','light','the']
def countwords(results):
    worddict = {}
    for result in results:
        if result in worddict:
            worddict[result] += 1
        else:
            worddict[result] = 1
    return worddict
```